# How to do photo tagging using codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, database, image, codeigniter

I want to add photo tagging feature to my system.  I referred this tutorial: 
http://techlister.com/php/simple-photo-tagging-with-php-and-jquery/1176/

I'm using codeigniter framework and I want to convert this into codeigniter.  But here data doesn't save in database.  Please can anyone help me to solve this issue.  Here is my code:

view-test_view.php:

```
// Save button click - save tagsfe
$( document ).on( 'click',  '#tagit #btnsave', function(){
    name = $('#tagname').val();
    var img = $('#imgtag').find( 'img' );
    var id = $( img ).attr( 'id' );
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url().'test_model/insert_imageData'; ?>", //model name
        data: "pic_id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&pic_x=" + mouseX + "&pic_y=" + mouseY + "&type=insert",
        cache: true,
        success: function(data) {
            viewtag( id );
            $('#tagit').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

model-test_model.php:

```
public function insert_imageData()
    {
            $data = array(
                'id' => $this->input->post('pic_id'),
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'pic_x' => $this->input->post('pic_x'),
                'pic_y' => $this->input->post('pic_y')
            );

             $this->db->insert('image_tag', $data);
    }
```

controller-
......................

```
 public function addImageData()
    {
         $this->load->model('test_model');
         $this->test_model->insert_imageData();

    }
```

Comment: What are the errors returned by CodeIgniter ?

Comment: @angezanetti I changed code little bit  still data don't save in database and no errors showing .I updated my code.Please check